# How to quickly get code from Kaggle notebook without requiring registration?

Tags: kaggle

I can already see three ways, but none are quick (not compared to say, accessing a `raw` file on github)

1. Fork/download (requires registration)
2. Follow instructions [here](https://www.kaggle.com/questions-and-answers/66085) (i.e. download, open up in jupyter/ipython notebook)
3. Copy the code blocks manually, one by one (bad for long notebooks)

Is there an easier way? (I hoping, ideally, to add `raw` to the url somewhere, just like on github)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it's useful to others, put the notebook url [here](http://kaggleraw.herokuapp.com/) to extract raw code